# Why does the prediction interval of deterministic trend become wider over time using R?

Tags: r

My prediction interval of a deterministic trend model becomes wider over time. Theoretically, it should be constant, right?

My code is:

```
x.est <- window(x,end=c(2006,12))
x.for <- window(x,start=c(2007,1))
x.reg <- tslm(x.est~trend)<br>
x.pre <- forecast(x.reg,h=length(x.for),level=95)
```

The prediction interval becomes wider:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you used `tslm` for forecasting on your timeseries, it would be important to see that `tslm` is used to fit linear models and both trend and seasonality components to the time series, taking the prediction horizon and the confidence level as parameters.

Forecast intervals increase in length as the forecasting horizons (`h=length(x.for)` in this case) increase. So, the longer the forecasting horizon gets, the wider(or broader) the forecasting interval gets as the uncertainty increases.

This might not be the case for non-linear forecasting techniques like `snaive`, etc

You might want to have a look at this [excellent article](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/7) for understanding better about forecasting intervals and how they get influenced with the forecasting horizons.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. My confusion is that it is our task to provide a single number of predition width for the sequence of predictions. If the predition width is actually increasing, the task makes no sense. But in theory, the prediction interval of deterministic trend does not change as we are using y_hat=a_hat+b_hat*t. The prediction interval is calculated using the sample standard deviation estimates derived from the training set. Only for the stochastic trend model the prediction increases. Is that correct?

Comment: Only for the stochastic trend model the prediction width increases.

Comment: @Jessie.KKL For stochastic trend models, the prediction intervals would definitely increase. A small example can be: For a point, prediction interval can be [-2, 2]. So, now for the next point (I mean, the currently predicted point), the prediction interval would be a super set of all the prediction intervals of -2, -1, 0, 1 and 2 and so on....

So, as the horizon increases in length, the interval gets wider and wider.

And yours (**tslm**), being a linear model cannot account for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answers. I'm gonna ask our professor why he requires a single number of width while it's actually increasing for a deterministic trend.

Comment: @Jessie.KKL Great.  Do leave a comment here, in case your prof. enlightens you through a nice concept/theory.  So that, the CV folks can also have a chance to learn from it.

Comment: OK. I will definitely do that if he gives me the good reason. Thank you again.